# precise line-height like 16.666666666...px

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` with a `height=100px` .
Inside that `<div>` I want 6 lines of text. So mathematically my `line-height` is equal to `16.666666666...px`.

The problem is the `css` will round my `line-height` to `16.7px` for each line. As a result my last line will display in "overflow" inside my `div`. (on A4 size that sometimes hide two lines)

is there a way to script something like

```
$lineHeight = 16.66666666 ;
line1 starts at 1 * $lineHeight;
line2 starts at 2 * $lineHeight;
line3 starts at 3 * $lineHeight;
....
```

in order to stick with my `line-height` grid?

Comment: so make it `16.6` to avoid overflow

Comment: @TemaniAfif =))))))) yes well I can't. that's the issue. They provide files from indesign and I have to match their layout. but yes that would have been radical

Comment: you cannot avoid rouding .. in the real world there is no `16.666666...` so you will either have something smaller or bigger, Better have smaller.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Why did you remove my JS tag.. I think only JS can help me don't you think ?.

Comment: you didn't add JS tag, you added `java` tag which is not JS thus not relevant (like PHP one too)

Comment: @TemaniAfif of course in mathematics there is 16.66666. Are you bully me? for example an A4 is 21*29.694.......

Comment: In mathematics there is, but I said *in the real world* and there is a difference between `16.66666` and `16.6666....`. The first one can be defined and the second one no, and the the first one is smaller than the second one

Comment: *"They provide files from indesign and I have to match their layout."* You're the web designer. You need to explain to them that web media is different from print media. In particular, you do not have precise control over the layout down to the pixel.

Comment: @TemaniAfif can't you define sqrt(2) ?

Comment: @CodyGray yes of course but I can reduce the mistake to 1px instead of 60px if I have 60 lines ?

Comment: In computer you can only approximate the sqrt(2), you can never have the exact value of the mathematic sqrt(2) .. I think it's trivial that Irrational number (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number) cannot be defined exactly. You can only approximate them and control the error (like we do with the famous PI number)

Comment: How much significant digits did you want ?

Comment: @Morse Are all these situations defined as clearly as the example? I mean, is it always a matter of fitting XX lines in YY pixels? If so, you can calculate the rounding manually. In the example, give most of the lines a 17px line height, but every 3rd child a 16px line height, using `nth-child(3n)`.

Comment: also you can use `calc` in css as:`line-height: calc(100px / 6)`

Comment: @לבנימלכה Sadly, no. `calc(100px / 6)` results in the exact same 16.6666666 that causes the rounding errors in the first place.

Comment: At the current state of the browser render engines you will never get an accurate result that is consistent across browsers and os. And there is no general workaround for that. If you can limit the project to a certain render engine then the one of Firefox might be the best option. At least for the line height it has a consistent result, without under or overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a flex box and forget about the 16.666666667 line height.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container div {
  font: 10px/10px 'Arial', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>child 1</div>
  <div>child 2</div>
  <div>child 3</div>
  <div>child 4</div>
  <div>child 5</div>
  <div>child 6</div>
</div>
```

This works for any number of children and any height of the container. As long as the heights of the children don't add up to more than the height of the container.

Comment: I think the challenging part is that it's a whole block of text not diffente divs which make it not easy to control.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest using JavaScript to turn the lines into divs. The OP already indicated they were not opposed to using JavaScript.

Comment: @MrLister Thank you, and that exports well with wkhtmltopdf !

Comment: @Morse Ehm, you never mentioned that the ultimate goal was to create a PDF.

Comment: @MrLister you have no idea how ambitious this is... they want to recreate indesign in html5...